# How do you stop Pandas DataFrame.groupby() changing dtype from object to float when group column only contains nan values?

Tags: python, pandas, nan

When I run the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"S": ["xx", np.nan, np.nan], "V": [1.1,2.1,3.1]})
a = df.groupby(["S"], as_index=False, dropna=False).sum()
print(a.dtypes)
```

I get the following result, as expected:

```
S     object
V    float64
```

However, if I select a subset of rows that happen only to contain `nan` values:

```py
df2 = df.iloc[1:,:]
a2 = df2.groupby(["S"], as_index=False, dropna=False).sum()
print(a2.dtypes)
```

the `S` column in the resulting DataFrame is converted to a float which breaks subsequent code.

```
S    float64
V    float64
dtype: object
```

Is there any way of preventing this inferring of types and always keep the original type of `S`?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible. But a2 and df2 contain the same values, where df2 has the original dtypes. So why not just use df2?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the code, it should have read `df2 = df.iloc[1:,:]` not `df2 = df.iloc[1:2,:]` (now corrected). So `a2` is an aggregation of the two rows in `df2`

Comment: The explanation is here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html. np.nan actually is a float. It's an object first because it's an instance of a Numpy object.

Comment: Yes, I realize that `nan` is a float. My question is why the groupby() function insists on narrowing the dtype of the column to a float rather than keeping it as an object as it was in `df` and still was in `df2`. Knowing where this problem might occur, I can code around it and change the dtype back, but this is not nice generic code and the behavior seems inconsistent with the `iloc` operation.

Comment: If you convert the object to a float rightaway, it won’t change back to object. That way you can account for float in the rest of your code.

Comment: The point is that it can't, in general, be a float, as it sometimes contains strings. That is why the type is an object and why I want it to remain an object type. It seems like if I have pandas 1.0.0 or greater I might be able to use [StringDtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.StringDtype.html#pandas.StringDtype)

Comment: I've just had this bite me. I consider it a bug in pandas. Just because a single group has only null values, why change the column dtype which I've already specified previously?? It took me a long time to work out this is what was happening.